# JMenuItem.getRootPane() workaround?

Tags: java, swing

It seems to be [well-known](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6499857) there is a bug when using JMenuItem.getRootPane().
I read the bug description but i cannot figure out a workaround.
Do you know work-around code for this in an Action.actionPerformed() method ?

**Update**: I get this now but that don't work with sub-menus.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
        if (c instanceof JMenuItem) {
            c = ((JPopupMenu)((JMenuItem)c).getParent()).getInvoker();
        }

        Component z  = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(c);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. You can't just keep using getParent() because each sub menu has its own popup menu. So you have to find all the menus in the chain until you find a JMenu with a JMenuBar as its parent. Then you can use that menu to look up the root pane. Something like this:

```
public JMenu getMenuBarMenu(JMenuItem item)
{
    JMenuItem menu = null;

    while (menu == null)
    {
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)item.getParent();
        item = (JMenuItem)popup.getInvoker();

        if (item.getParent() instanceof JMenuBar)
            menu = item;
    }

    return (JMenu)menu;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to initialize the `Action` with whatever it needs to work on, and if necessary to create separate action instances for each context (each window, or whatever). Certainly the code will be easier to read. :)

Comment: I had this before but i don't think the code is significant easier to read and i cannot use the default Action contructor w/o arguments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get this workaround work with sub-menu, you'll need to add a another .getParent()
Example:
((JPopupMenu)((JMenuItem)((JMenuItem)c).getParent()).getParent()).getInovker();